# tinymce is deleting everything inside iframe laravel

Tags: laravel, iframe, tinymce

What happens when I add a normal iframe in my tinymce:

[image: What happens when I add a normal iframe in my tinymce]

Laravel tinymce options

[image: Laravel tinymce options]

So guys, my client need to add some iVoox iframes into his post and tinymce is deleting them. I added those iframe options in my extended_valid_elements but still not working.

What can I do?

Comment: How does Laravel come into play here?

Comment: The website is build with Laravel. Thought maybe was important to point that was not a Wordpress site. (I'm not a dev).